# Returning a maximum number of items the LINQ way

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a search module with an underlying data repository, and a requirement to return a maximum of 25 results from the search query. I can enforce this with a Take() operation:

```
IEnumerable<Contact> Search(string name)
{
    // validation/cleanup on name parameter

    IEnumerable<Contact> matching = _repository.Search(name);
    return matching.Take(25);
}
```

Next, suppose I have an additional requirement to throw an exception if more than 25 results would be returned (i.e. the search parameter is too broad). Is there a straightforward way to do this with LINQ? The closest I have come so far is to take one more than the maximum number and work with that:

```
IEnumerable<Contact> Search(string name)
{
    // validation/cleanup on name parameter

    var matching = _repository.Search(name);
    var toReturn = matching.Take(26).ToList();
    if (toReturn.Count() > 25)
    {
        throw new Exception("Too many results");
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

However, this seems a bit clunkier than necessary.

Comment: where is this number "25" coming from? is it passed in as a parameter?

Comment: Could you just check the `Count()` on `matching`?

Comment: The `Single` methods do similar to what you suggest. `SELECT TOP 2` and throw an error if two were returned.

Comment: It's just an extra conditional, so I wouldn't call it clunky. In any case it's easy to write a `NoMoreThan` extension method and keep the main code flow tidy.

Comment: Only change I'd make is removing the `()` on `Count` to emphasize it's a materialized list, not a lazy enumerable.

Comment: The problem with checking Count() on matching is you have to enumerate through it to get the count, then the consumer of "my" method will need to enumerate through it again. Without knowledge of the underlying class implementing IEnumerable, you don't have any guarantees that it can be enumerated more than once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your method is the best method.  I would not make any changes at all.

Any other option, such as querying the count alone first is performing what appears to be an expensive operation (doing the actual searching) twice in the event that you have less than 26 items.  You save only a little tiny bit in the error case and add a significant expense in the common case.

The only time your code would be less desirable is if `_repository.Search(name)` returned a type that could be cheaply iterated twice and that could cheaply provide it's count (like, say, a `List`) but in context that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions about the repository or the actual type of the IEnumerable returned from it.

Comment: @EricPohl Well, when performing a performance analysis you have to do exactly that.  In many cases there is no one option that is always better in every regard no matter what, in most cases making one thing better makes something else worse.  If you're unwilling to make any assumptions about the data at all then you effectively can't compare different methods beyond which ones produce the right output and which don't.  Now in my eyes it's much more likely, and also safer, to assume that the underlying assumption can't be efficiently iterated twice, but that is an assumption.

Comment: I would make one change - use `Count` rather than `Count()` given that you've already got a list.

Comment: @JonSkeet I consider that a style change more than anything.  There are several style-based changes that I would make if it were personally my method; I'm referring to specifically any changes that would have a perceptible change in the result or speed of the method.

Comment: @Servy: Okay. I wouldn't have said anything if you hadn't said you "would not make any changes at all" :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own generic iterator block extension method and use it for any `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeWithMaximum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int maxCount)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        int count = 0;
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (++count > maxCount)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("More than the maximum specified number of elements ({0}) were returned.", maxCount));

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't throw an exception until you ask for the 26th item, rather than when you ask for the first.  That doesn't appear to be the requested functionality.  If there are 26 items *none* should be returned.